# Transparent background from the grand-parent element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply to an element transparent background, but directly to the grand parent element. for example:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, rgba(5, 175, 240, 0.14), rgba(239, 77, 54, 0.14), rgba(243, 200, 57, 0.14)) fixed
}

.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: // here, i want the background to reflect the body background
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `span` won't accept `height` or `width` as long as it has its default `display: inline`. Aside from that, there is no way to achieve what you want in CSS.

Comment: you right, just for the example. there is a way to do that with js?

Comment: Cant you use CSS variables?

Comment: i can, but this is a gradient and it'll look ugly

Answer (score 0):

No need of span you can achieve this using clip-path CSS property

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, rgba(5, 175, 240, 0.14), rgba(239, 77, 54, 0.14), rgba(243, 200, 57, 0.14)) fixed
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 50px, 50px 50px, 50px 0%, 85% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 15%, 100% 85%, 100% 100%, 85% 100%, 15% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 85%);
}
```

```html
<div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: i need to add content into the child, so i cant use clip-path

Answer (score 0):

Use the same gradient for both elements

```css
body {
  --g: linear-gradient( 45deg, rgba(5, 175, 240, 0.14), rgba(239, 77, 54, 0.14), rgba(243, 200, 57, 0.14)) fixed;
  background: var(--g)
}

.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: var(--g);
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i cant. i have an opacity on the background, and it look ugly in light mode / dark mode toggle

Comment: @YeudaBy such constraint need to go into your question to get accurate answers. We give answers based on the requirement inside your question not based on the requirements *you* only know.

Comment: I gave this information... the `rgba` looks pretty clear to me

Comment: @YeudaBy you didn't give the information of light/dark mode. The rbga is not an issue as you can see in my answer. The child is having the same gradient as the body like stated in the question

Comment: i know, i tried your awnser and in dark mode it works well, only in light mode it didnt, because the opacity.